# TeamCity unmet requirement: MSBuildTools12.0_x86_Path exists (Mac only)

Tags: macos, msbuild, teamcity

I've seen this question asked but never specifically for Mac.  My company is using TeamCity on a Mac Mini to do our iOS and android builds.  We would use windows but, iOS builds require a Mac with Xcode. I have not been able to satisfy this condition.  I can see that there are multiple versions of MSBuild (and Xbuild) already on my machine.  Here is what I tried:

- set an environment variable for MSBuildTools12.0_x86_Path using launchctl setenv (tried the bin directory of every instance of MSBuild existing on my machine), rebooted before checking TC
- setting env.MSBuildTools12.0_x86_Path entry in buildAgent.properties
- setting system.MSBuildTools12.0_x86_Path entry in buildAgent.properties
- logging into TeamCity, going to my build configuration, going to the "parameters" tab and adding a new parameter for env.MSBuildTools12.0_x86_Path

After all of the above failed to satisfy the condition, I tried grabbing version 12 of MSBuild from a Windows machine, copying it to my Mac and pointing to its "Bin" directory instead, and repeating all bullets above.
The path was /Users/myusername/MSBuild/12.0/Bin.  This bin directory contains MSBuild.exe, an MSBuild folder, a bunch of DLLs and more.

Again, this failed to change the outcome of the unmet condition in TeamCity.  The frustrating thing is that TeamCity isn't giving me details.  I don't know if it's still complaining that the path isn't even set (and where it is even looking for that path definition), or if it SEES that the path is set but it's not pointing to a folder it recognizes as MSBuild.  I'm completely in the dark.

Does anyone have any guidance for me on this?  I feel I've exhausted all paths to a solution.  Thank you so much, in advance.

Comment: I had the wrong version of Visual Studio selected.  I have Visual Studio 2017 installed on my Mac.  Once I corrected it, the requirement became MSBuildTools15.0_x86_Path.  So I set it to the bin directory of VS2017 where MSBuild exists:  /Applications/Visual\ Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/bin but that didn't do a bit of good.  I have the same error except it's MSBuild 15 instead of 12.  I'm totally stuck here.

Comment: Could it be 32 bit vs. 64 bit?  It's looking for x86, not x64, but I see no way to set it to 64-bit in the build step for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on my own.  On the Mac, you have to do an "MSBuild" runner type and pick "Mono xbuild 4.5" for the version.  I used "x86" for the run platform and set a parameter for Mono4.5_x86 to point to xbuild.  But it was trying to run the 64 bit version of mono and I found no way to set a command line argument for mono to tell it I want --arch=32 so I ended up having to link the mono executable to mono-sgen32 to get the build to finally work.